# Debug output from webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, webrat

Are there any ways to see debug output from webrat on failed steps?

For example I get the following error:

```
The 'Test User' option was not found in the "user_id" select box (Webrat::NotFoundError)
```

I want to see HTML output that webrat is seeing, to figure out, where is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out myself. Webrat has `save_and_open_page` method, it saves HTML page to `tmp/` dir and opens it in browser.